# What would cause files to be excluded from Windows Search Indexer unexpectedly?

Tags: windows-search

I have a series of folders (lesson1, lesson2, etc.), and each one contains an "fla" (Flash) file for the lesson.

In the parent directory, I typed "`*.fla`" into the search box to list all the fla files in subfolders so I could load them more quickly for editing.  I dragged a few of them into Flash, edited them, and saved them.  Then I noticed they disappeared from the search results momentarily, and some of them eventually came back, but not all of them.

I realized after verifying the file was there and named correctly, that there must be some kind of glitch in windows indexing, because even a search for "*" in the file's own directory was returning nothing.

I changed the file name, and changed it back, thinking that would trigger the file system watcher to reindex the file, and that worked.  The question is how it managed to escape watch in the first place.

With this kind of unreliability, I can't use the search feature at all dependably to ensure I process all the files in subdirectories.  Is there any way to force it to refresh the index on a folder and subfolders without having it attempt to completely rebuild the index for the entire system?

Comment: The sad thing is, this is reproducable.  I had 10 files selected, dragged them into flash, edited them, and saved them, and when I look back at Windows Explorer, only 4 of the 10 files are still listed.  The rest have been purged from the windows search index, so I'll have to identify which ones and manually rename them, or rebuild the entire index and wait for it.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: in the meantime use Everything by voidtools, though even that can be unrelaible but just delete everything.db and restart it. But if you haven't tried Everything, then you should, it's life changing.

Answer (score 0):

File Explorer displays a folders contents. Search displays its results until refreshed (F5).